# Recursive function - Don't show directory if empty

Tags: c#, recursion

I´m creating a web application that needs to list all the files and directories in a specific folder.
I´ve created the resurvice function to list these, but another specification is that if the directory has no files then the directory shouldn´t be shown.

Now the problem is, what if i have a directory with a submenu, with a submenu, with a submenu, with a submenu and only the last submenu has files in it. It still needs to show all the other directories.

I´ve no idea how to achieve this, any code or tips would be appreciated!

My current recursive function:

```
private List<FolderModel> GetFolderSubFolders(IFolderInfo folder)
    {
        var retval = new List<FolderModel>();

        // Foreach subfolder in the given folder
        foreach (var subFolder in FolderManager.Instance.GetFolders(folder))
        {
                // Create new foldermodel
                var folderModel = new FolderModel
                {
                    FolderName = subFolder.FolderName,
                    Bestanden = GetFolderBestanden(subFolder),
                    // Recall this function
                    SubFolders = GetFolderSubFolders(subFolder)
                };

            // Check if we have files and subfolders
            if (folderModel.Bestanden.Any() && folderModel.SubFolders.Any())
            {
                folderModel.hasFilesAndFolders = true;
            }

            retval.Add(folderModel);

        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: you want to hide empty folders or show?

Comment: Hide the folders, if there arent any files in it (including sub folders)

Answer (score 0):

Just let it find all directories and then filter for the ones which have files inside:

```
List<FolderModel> allFolders = GetFolderSubFolders(myFolder);

List<FolderModel> nonEmptyFolders = allFolders.Where(f => f.HasFiles).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried to run this but I think something like that should work:

```
private List<FolderModel> GetFolderSubFolders(IFolderInfo folder)
{
    var retval = new List<FolderModel>();

    // Foreach subfolder in the given folder
    foreach (var subFolder in FolderManager.Instance.GetFolders(folder))
    {
        // Recall this function
        List<FolderModel> subFolders = GetFolderSubFolders(subFolder);
        // I am assuming that "Bestanden" is also a List<T> and contains
        // the files of this folder
        List<Something> bestanden = GetFolderBestanden(subFolder);
        // Don't do anything if an empty list was returned
        if(subFolders.Count > 0 || bestanden.Count > 0)
        {
            // Create new foldermodel
            var folderModel = new FolderModel
            {
                FolderName = subFolder.FolderName,
                Bestanden = bestanden,
                SubFolders = subFolders
            };

            // Check if we have files and subfolders
            if (folderModel.Bestanden.Any() && folderModel.SubFolders.Any())
            {
                folderModel.hasFilesAndFolders = true;
            }

            retval.Add(folderModel);
        }
    }
    // If nothing was found this will return an empty list
    return retval;
}
```

The idea is that you don't return anything if you don't find something at the last level. The above may not work as I've not run it but you may get a hint.